# How do i solve an internal server error in a flask application?

Tags: python, flask

I tried writing a simple scraper for extracting all the html code of github home page, but  i keep getting a status response code of 500 (internal server error)

here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

app = Flask(__name__)

d = {
     "site":"https://github.com"
     }


@app.route("/")
def index():

    URL = "https://github.com"
    page = requests.get(URL)
    tree = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")
    return tree.prettify()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Please how do i overcome this ?

Comment: You need to look at the server log look into the terminal you run the server

Comment: I ran this code and it pretty much works. What is the stackrace?

Comment: stackrace? i don't understand

Answer (score 0):

At first try the code didn't run on my machine to. The problem was not installed dependencies. Make sure you have following packages installed (with `pip` for example):

```
flask
requests
bs4
html5lib
```

Comment: they are all installed but i am still getting an error